# How to make a search form using jquery and razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have made an CRUD application using webmatrix. I am using jquery and razor syntax. As I am still learning, took me long to figure out how to use jquery and implement it in my asp.net.

Below is the code I have done:

```
 $('#grid').click({
                 function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
//javascript code here

</script>
</head>
<body>
input type="text" name="fname"><<input type="button" value="Submit form">

<div id="grid" class="ui-widget">
    @RenderPage("~/Partials/Recipient.cshtml")
</div>
```

I am interested in a way where when I click the submit button the value in my text box is posted to my Recpient.cshtml and executed, Then it is rendered underneath the search.
I am stuck here where I need to post the input value to Partials/Recipient.cshtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you configure your ajax call (which would send the value of your `fname` input field as a `POST` parameter to your `Recipient.cshtml` script), then process `Recipient.cshtml` output on success.

It should look like:

```
$.ajax({
url: "Partials/Recipient.cshtml",
type: "POST",
data: { fname: $('input[name$="fname"]').val() }
success: function(ajaxoutput)
{
    //dosomething();
}
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am looking for a way to post and display the webgrid. The post is just one value.

Comment: then your success function should probably be something like `$('#grid').html(ajaxoutput);` (that would replace your "grid" div content with the ouput from the ajax call to Recipient.cshtml)